# Best coding approach to scroll long text and images horizontally in WPF/XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smooth text animation (Marquee) using WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002271/smooth-text-animation-marquee-using-wpf)

I am just wondering if there is some **best coding approach** ***to scroll*** text and images horizontally in WPF?

Basically I used some code to do it like

```
        private void PopulateCanvas()
                {

                    canvas1.Width = RootGrid.ActualWidth;
                    canvas1.Height = RootGrid.ActualHeight;

                    foreach (var item in PluginContentItems)
                    {
                        if (IsImage(item.IPluginContentItemElements))
                        {
                            string imageName = GetImageName(item.IPluginContentItemElements);

                            if (IsGifImage(item.IPluginContentItemElements))
                                AddGIFImage(imageName);
                            else
                                AddImage(imageName);
                        }
                        else // Text
                        {
                            string text = GetText(item.IPluginContentItemElements);
                            SolidColorBrush brush = GetFontColor(item.IPluginContentItemElements);
                            AddTextBlock(text, brush);
                        }
                    }

                    canvas1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(Object state)
                    {
                        var node = textBlocks.First;

                        while (node != null)
                        {
                            if (node.Previous != null)
                            {
                                if (node.Previous.Value.GetType().FullName.Contains("TextBlock"))
                                    Canvas.SetLeft(node.Value, Canvas.GetLeft((TextBlock)node.Previous.Value) + ((TextBlock)node.Previous.Value).ActualWidth); // + gap
                                else if (node.Previous.Value.GetType().FullName.Contains("GifImage"))
                                    Canvas.SetLeft(node.Value, Canvas.GetLeft((GifImage)node.Previous.Value) + ((GifImage)node.Previous.Value).ActualWidth); // + gap
                                else if (node.Previous.Value.GetType().FullName.Contains("Controls.Image"))
                                    Canvas.SetLeft(node.Value, Canvas.GetLeft((Image)node.Previous.Value) + ((Image)node.Previous.Value).ActualWidth); // + gap
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (node.Value.GetType().FullName.Contains("TextBlock"))
                                    Canvas.SetLeft((TextBlock)node.Value, canvas1.Width); // + gap
                                if (node.Value.GetType().FullName.Contains("Image"))
                                    Canvas.SetLeft((Image)node.Value, canvas1.Width); // + gap
                                if (node.Value.GetType().FullName.Contains("GifImage"))
                                    Canvas.SetLeft((GifImage)node.Value, canvas1.Width); // + gap
                            }

                            node = node.Next;
                        }

                        return null;

                    }), null);

                }


     void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                canvas1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(Object state)
                {
                    var node = textBlocks.First;
                    var lastNode = textBlocks.Last;

                    while (node != null)
                    {
                        double newLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(node.Value) - move_amount;

                        double w1 = 0;

                        if (node.Value is TextBlock)
                            w1 = ((TextBlock)node.Value).ActualWidth;

                        if (node.Value is Image)
                            w1 = ((Image)node.Value).ActualWidth;

                        if (node.Value is GifImage)
                            w1 = ((GifImage)node.Value).ActualWidth;

                        if (newLeft < (0 - w1)) // + gap
                        {
                            textBlocks.Remove(node);

                            var lastNodeLeftPos = Canvas.GetLeft(lastNode.Value);

                            textBlocks.AddLast(node);

                            if (lastNode.Value.GetType().FullName.Contains("TextBlock"))
                            {
                                // + gap
                                if ((lastNodeLeftPos + ((TextBlock)lastNode.Value).ActualWidth) > canvas1.Width) // Last element is offscreen
                                    newLeft = lastNodeLeftPos + ((TextBlock)lastNode.Value).ActualWidth; // + gap
                                else
                                    newLeft = canvas1.Width; //  +gap;
                            }
                            else if (lastNode.Value.GetType().FullName.Contains("GifImage"))
                            { // + gap
                                if ((lastNodeLeftPos + ((GifImage)lastNode.Value).ActualWidth) > canvas1.Width) // Last element is offscreen
                                    newLeft = lastNodeLeftPos + ((GifImage)lastNode.Value).ActualWidth; // + gap
                                else
                                    newLeft = canvas1.Width; // + gap
                            }
                            else if (lastNode.Value.GetType().FullName.Contains("Controls.Image"))
                            { // + gap
                                if ((lastNodeLeftPos + ((Image)lastNode.Value).ActualWidth) > canvas1.Width) // Last element is offscreen
                                    newLeft = lastNodeLeftPos + ((Image)lastNode.Value).ActualWidth; // + gap
                                else
                                    newLeft = canvas1.Width; // + gap
                            }
                        }

                        Canvas.SetLeft(node.Value, newLeft);

                        node = node == lastNode ? null : node.Next;
                    }

                    return null;

                }), null);
            }


private void AddGIFImage(string file)
        {
            try
            {
                string pathToImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(Settings.ContentFolderPath, file);

                Uri u = new Uri(pathToImage);
                GifImage gif = new GifImage(u);
                gif.Height = canvas1.Height; //  canvas1.Height / koeffImage;
                canvas1.Children.Add(gif);
                Canvas.SetTop(gif, 0);
                Canvas.SetLeft(gif, -999);
                textBlocks.AddLast(gif);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HasError = true;
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        private void AddImage(string file)
        {
            try
            {
                string pathToImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(Settings.ContentFolderPath, file);

                Image image = new Image();
                BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
                src.BeginInit();
                src.UriSource = new Uri(pathToImage, UriKind.Absolute);
                src.EndInit();
                double ratio = src.Width / src.Height;
                image.Source = src;
                image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                image.Height = canvas1.Height;
                image.Width = canvas1.Height * ratio;
                canvas1.Children.Add(image);
                Canvas.SetTop(image, 0);
                Canvas.SetLeft(image, -999);
                textBlocks.AddLast(image);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HasError = true;
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        void AddTextBlock(string Text, SolidColorBrush color)
        {
            try
            {
                double w = MeasureTextSize(Text, fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontStretch, fontSize).Width;

                TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                tb.Text = Text;
                tb.FontSize = 28;
                tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
                tb.Foreground = color;
                // tb.Background = Brushes.Blue;
                tb.FontSize = fontSize = canvas1.Height / koeff;
                tb.Width = w;

                canvas1.Children.Add(tb);

                Canvas.SetTop(tb, 0);
                Canvas.SetLeft(tb, -9999);

                textBlocks.AddLast(tb);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HasError = true;
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @H.B.  Right.. And what? Are you ready to answer?

Comment: That was supposed to be hint that you are doing to much in C#, 90% of that image adding code could be replaced by XAML (which even would take less than half of the space)

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002271/smooth-text-animation-marquee-using-wpf) and [here](http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2008/08/silverlight-marquee-control.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user specified in the comments, you should do this in XAML. It's easier, cleaner and yes, it is a best practice. You can use a `ListBox` of Items and just play with it's `ItemsPanel` data template. I also recommend further learning on [Storyboards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx).