# How to make text as marquee in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Here I have code to scroll the text in wpf using Translate transform as

```
   <TextBlock x:Name="_box" FontSize="64"  Text="lorem ipsum">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>

        <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform" X="0" Y="0" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                From="-300" To="300" Duration="0:0:5" 
                AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

How to write this code programmtically in wpf using translate transform in c#, please help me any one. i tried but strucked at textblock to add translate transform in render transform.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002271/smooth-text-animation-marquee-using-wpf

Answer (score 2):

```
void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

        doubleAnimation.From = -tbmarquee.ActualWidth;

        doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualWidth;

        doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:10"));

        tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, doubleAnimation);

    }
```

Link:

http://weblogs.asp.net/razan/archive/2009/10/01/creating-marquee-scrolling-text-in-wpf.aspx